# Over Query Limit - Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google

i have the following code to display dynamically generated addresses on google maps.

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.9027636, 49.8988135),
        maxZoom: 18,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

        geocodeAddress(locations, i);
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function geocodeAddress(locations, i) {
    var title = locations[i][0];
    var address = locations[i][1];
    var url = locations[i][2];
    var markerImage = locations[i][3];
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': locations[i][1]
    },

    function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                //icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png',
                icon: markerImage,
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                title: title,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                address: address,
                url: url
            })
            infoWindow(marker, map, title, address, url);
            bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        } else {
            alert("geocode of " + address + " failed:" + status);
        }
    });
}

function infoWindow(marker, map, title, address, url) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        var html = "<div><h3>" + title + "</h3><p>" + address + "<br></div><a href='" + url + "'>Eintrag anzeigen</a></p></div>";
        iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: html,
            maxWidth: 350
        });
        iw.open(map, marker);
    });
}

function createMarker(results) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png',
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        title: title,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        address: address,
        url: url
    })
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    infoWindow(marker, map, title, address, url);
    return marker;
}
```

The Addresses came over this:

```
 var locations = <?php echo json_encode($addresses, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Now I have 12 addresses, which are generated dynamically and I get an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error.
Under 12, there is no error.

Do any of you have a tip how to prevent this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: sounds like your geocoding too fast (or without an api key) you need to spread them out time wise, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/geocoding-strategies

Comment: i´m working with an api-key. yes - but i don´t know how in this matter...
Any advice further....?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792916/over-query-limit-in-google-maps-api-v3-how-do-i-pause-delay-in-javascript-to-sl